# Review audits with deleted posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, review-audits

When reviewing, it is possible to edit the post that is presented. However, when what you are reviewing is actually a review audit and you click edit, the following message appears:

> This post is deleted and cannot be edited.

See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15947817/edit)

Doesn't this kind of give the game away? It's literally telling you that you need to flag the post as it's an audit. When you do so you'll get the Congratulations message, giving you a free review point.

Is this a problem? Should this be Changed?

Comment: If you want to edit, you are paying attention. So then it's okay to pass the audit.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sure, but one could just click edit on every review without reading it, just to check if it's an audit.

Comment: @JackPettinger: One could click flag on every audit as well to check.

Comment: @JackPettinger: Editing every post (then hitting back, then hitting Approve) takes at least as long as glancing at the content to see if it's an audit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you thought that it could be improved and went for the edit button, you're not robo-reviewing. Flaggable and editable posts have an overlap region, there are posts which I may not be able to improve, but you can.

Ideally the edit button should trigger the "Congratulations!" message, but this works too.

---

The edit button could be used to check for audits, but so can the flag button (the audit system is quite easy to bypass, but anyone willing to put that much work into writing a bypassing userscript probably could make better use of their time by just reviewing normally)

Comment: I am of the opinion that the "deleted post" message is completely misleading, especially considering the reviewer is kicked back into review mode and is trapped.  There is nothing more for the user to do and he is unable to click "I'm Done", which is what should be enabled at that point.

Comment: This just happened to me! I clicked edit, arrived at a "this post has been deleted" page, thought I was done, pressed the back button and said "Nothing to do here" and... 

`You failed to pass this test` Sigh.

Comment: I feel pretty strongly about this too. I tried to translate a post into English which was an okay answer, but it was deleted (which is also okay). I figured if it's deleted, there is no action necessary. I think this got me three times, so now I guess I'll skip or go for flagging, but I really don't like flagging when I know I could have edited or assisted in some way to fix it.