# Bug with test in review queue

Tags: discussion, edits, review

I just got audited on a review, and found a problem with the test. I clicked on edit, and it told me that the post was deleted and could not be edited. I just figured it had been deleted just then and I went back. I decided to flag it and move on, and the test notification appeared. An edit probably wouldn't fix an unsuitable answer, so I'm not sure if a congratulations message should appear, but I also don't think that it should count as a fail, and I definitely don't think that it should say that the post is deleted.

Can someone think of a good solution? Maybe passing is correct?

Comment: Exact duplicate: [Review audits with deleted posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177130)

Comment: Edited, as this is by-design and not really a bug report.

Comment: Wow! I searched multiple queries and didn't find anything! Thanks.