# Deleted or protected posts appearing under review audits

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits

Related post: [Review audits with deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177130/212576)

With the new `add comment` button; [a review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/3037744) with a deleted post appears as follows:

[image: Review Audit]

Once I know that the post is either locked (recently?) or deleted, I'm sure that it is certainly a review audit. Doesn't that beat the purpose of an audit? Once I know that the post has had one of the following action taken on it:

- The entire thread had been locked!
- The current post was deleted by community or a moderator!

I'm sure to know that it is an audit. These kind of things can also be picked up by robo-reviewers and they'd be sure to pass these.

Comment: The purpose of an audit is to make sure you're paying attention, so you technically passed.